# AppArg files not copied in the ...../Documents/Inbox folder (iOS simulator) when selected or drag/dropped

Tags: java, ios, ios-simulator, codenameone, info.plist

I am testing a CodenameOne app in the iOS simulator.

The app can manage files with a custom extension, it can import/export them through the "private" Documents folder, that is exposed to the Files app and iTunes.
This feature works. The file path is something like:

```
file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/alphanumeric string here/data/Containers/Data/Application/another alphanumeric string here/Documents/filename.ext
```

Now, among the build hints for the app there is the plist inject part, that correctly includes all the necessary tags for a complete handling of files with custom extension.
This kind of files can be selected in the Files app, or even dragged and dropped from the OSX host system. The injected part was taken from a sample Swift app created with Xcode itself (Document app).

This different feature also works on the app side because the app is foregrounded every time and the AppArg parameter is passed.

The relevant code is something like:

```
public void start()
{
...
...
String arg=Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg",null);

    if (arg!=null)
    {

            importArg(arg);

    }
}
```

The format of the file path is the same, except that the Documents/Inbox folder is used.
In fact it is CodenameOne system that works under the hood to handle this.

Here's an example:

```
file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/alphanumeric string here/data/Containers/Data/Application/another alphanumeric string here/Documents/Inbox/filename.ext
```

The Inbox folder is not displayed but it is already present. The build hint

```
ios.newStorageLocation=true
```

is used, which makes

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots()[0]
```

return the Documents path, as usual.

But when a custom file is selected, or drag/dropped there is a "File not found:" error in the log, indeed it seems that the file is not copied in the Inbox subfolder at all.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public static String readTextFileFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {

    try(InputStream is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(url);) 
{
                 return Util.readToString(is);

}  catch(IOException err) 
{
String error=err.getMessage();
System.out.println(error); //this is where the error is printed to console
}

return null;

}
```

(This code works when the user imports a file from the Documents folder)

Similar error when attempting to open a custom file from the iCloud drive on the simulator.

In both cases the path is passed, but it seems that the file is not effectively copied to be available to the app.

I suspected that the Inbox subfolder was not present at all, so I put this code:

```
 String documentsRoot=MyUtils.getDocumentPath();
    com.codename1.io.File file=new File(documentsRoot+"Inbox");
    if (!file.exists())
    {

        file.mkdir();
        System.out.println("created Inbox "+file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Usually this code is not executed, no "created Inbox ..." is found in the console output. I think that the Inbox subfolder is already present.

But sometimes when it is executed and the app creates the Inbox itself, then the importing works, the file is read, and the Inbox file list shows the files in it.

So it is possible that CN1 creates that subfolder badly (permissions or whatever), while if the app creates it, it's available.

Is this an issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the code that actually throws the exception in `importArg`?

Comment: @Shai Almog I edited the post and included the code with the exception.

Comment: If you create a simple Swift or Objective-C app in Xcode (not using codename one), and try reading one of these paths from the Files app,  does it work?  As far as I know it won't let you read documents from another app's container.

Comment: @steve hannah Please read the added part of edited post.

Comment: Odd. If you'll go to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m` you will notice we don't really do anything with the file. We just pass it onward and don't have anything to do with that folder. Is that code hit? is the file there?